# Why am I not getting correct output with sort command

Tags: sort

This is what I have tried so far

```
sort /etc/passwd -t: -k1 > ~/passwd.bylogin
```

I keep getting an error that the output is wrong.

The question is:

> Sort the /etc/passwd file in alphabetically ascending order, using the user's login shell as your primary key. Store the results in the file newly created file passwd.bylogin

I don't understand why I am not getting the correct output.

Comment: It works for me. Post exact error you get.

Comment: You are unlikely to get an error with the exact string "that the output is wrong", cut and paste the real message.

Comment: And also try to run the command `sort -t: -k1 /etc/passwd` without output redirection, see if that works for you to home in on where in the combination the error is.

Comment: -k1 will sort on the first field. The shell isn't in the first field, is it?

Comment: This is the copied error message I received file 'passwd.bylogin' matches specified command
file does not match output
-k1 is the user who owns the process

Comment: Mark I think its in -k2 (PID). I will double check

Comment: No I tried -k2 and it was the same thing

Comment: If you type `cat /etc/passwd` and look for the field that looks like a user login shell, say, `/bin/sh`, which field is it?

Comment: Alternatively, if you type `man 5 passwd`, does it tell you which field has the login shell (also known as command interpreter)?

Comment: No I checked man5 and cat

Comment: You should improve your question, **NOT** copy output in a comment, it is still unclear what you wrote and what you copied.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. You need to show us your expected output, the output you are getting and the _exact_ error message returned.

Comment: Is this homework?, if so add homework tag, to we can give correct level of help. Tutor you instead of give you an answer. So you can do better on the next homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you're supposed to be sorting by the shell, which is the 7th field.  Thus, the following should work for you:

```
sort /etc/passwd -t: -k7 > ~/passwd.bylogin
```